# How to display from one model but save to another

Tags: xaml, mvvm, windows-8, windows-runtime

I have a `ListView` that a user can select multiple items from a `choreList`.  However, I'd like the items selected to save to another model that contains a list of `Chores`

Below is my attempt at that, but it isn't working.  The `personSingle` object contains 0 `assignedChores`

```
    <ListView x:Name="choreList" BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="1" Grid.Row="1" 
              DisplayMemberPath="Summary" ItemsSource="{Binding choreList, Mode=OneWay}"  
              SelectedValue="{Binding personSingle.assignedChores, Mode=TwoWay}"
              SelectionMode="Multiple"/>
```

What do I need to do to add the chores select to my `personSingle.assignedChores` list?

**Update with Answer:**

```
    private void choreList_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.RemovedItems.Count > 0) {
            foreach(win8Chores.Model.databaseTables.Chore item in e.RemovedItems)
            {
                win8Chores.Model.databaseTables.Chore myChore = new Model.databaseTables.Chore();
                myChore = item;
                VM.personSingle.assignedChores.Remove(myChore);
            }

        }

        if (e.AddedItems.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (win8Chores.Model.databaseTables.Chore item in e.AddedItems)
            {
                win8Chores.Model.databaseTables.Chore myChore = new Model.databaseTables.Chore();
                myChore = item;
                VM.personSingle.assignedChores.Add(myChore);
            }
        }
    }
```

XAML:

```
<ListView x:Name="choreList" BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="1" Margin="401,322,613,150" Grid.Row="1" 
          DisplayMemberPath="Summary" ItemsSource="{Binding choreList, Mode=OneWay}"  
         SelectionMode="Multiple" SelectionChanged="choreList_SelectionChanged"/>
```

I'm still wondering if there is a way to do this strictly using Binding.  But for now the SelectionChanged event worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a mutil-select ListView, you don't use the SelectedValue property with data binding.  You need to access the ListView.SelectedItems property to get the list of selected items.  Handle the SelectionChanged event to respond to changes.

Comment: I will try that tonight.

Comment: I found a way to do it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you implement the SelectionChanged event on the ListView, you can just set your `personSingle.assignedChores` to all the selected items in your choreList ListView. This also gives you more power over exactly how to add them.